# System.OutOfMemoryException on Windows Server 2008 R2 + ASP.NET 3.5

Tags: asp.net, windows-server-2008, asp.net-3.5, out-of-memory

Today, a production server at my work started to get this OutOfMemoryException, but as far as I know, there has not been any code updates to the website.

I pasted the stack trace below, but any ideas on what might be happening?
Basically, this header control, downloads a portions of a website from a remote server and includes it as part of the HTML.

Server Error in '/' Application.
    Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
    Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

```
Exception Details: System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

Source Error:

Line 58:         else
Line 59:         {
Line 60:             thisHeader = Cache[headerCacheKey].ToString() + "\n<!-- pulled from cache -->\n";
Line 61:         }
Line 62:         if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(thisHeader))


Source File: ...

Stack Trace:

[OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.]
   System.String.Concat(String str0, String str1) +66
   ASP.controls_header_ascx.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in ...:60
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +25
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +42
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +132
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +66
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +191
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +191
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2428
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line that the runtime is pointing you to (`Line 60` I believe) is not necessarily a cause of `System.OutOfMemoryException`. There might be some code that feeds the web cache with lots of information and doesn't release that information when it's no longer "valid" or "actual".

Anyway I suggest you to read these two articles first:

1. [Troubleshooting System.OutOfMemoryException](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webtopics/archive/2009/05/22/troubleshooting-system.outofmemoryexceptions-in-asp.net.aspx)
2. [Tracking down managed memory leaks (windbg)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2004/12/10/279612.aspx)

The second article helped me ALOT when I faced the same problem one day. Actually now I prefer `windbg` over other (often proprietary) software to find out where is a memory leak in the software.

You could also try using one of these very helpful tools to find out what causes memory leaks:

1. [dotTrace Memory profiler](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/download/index.html#mem32)
2. [ANTS Memory profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/)

In general I think it's a good practice to examine the software execution process using a memory profiler before deploying the software on the production environment.

Answer (score 3):

Are you are looping in Page_Load and within that loop concatenating a string?  String concatenation is VERY slow and with each concatenation a new string object is allocated and put on the heap.  `System.Text.StringBuilder` is a much more efficient way of doing this sort of operation.  Note: if only concatenating a few short strings it is not an issue, but if you believe it'll go beyond that, then StringBuilder is your friend.

HTH

Comment: It's possible that other components are using string concatenation. I have a feeling the memory leak is happening elsewhere because the component that is throwing the exception did not have this OutOfMemoryException before.

Comment: Is it a control that was made in-house?  If it's something that is paid for, then I would contact the company that produced it and see if they can help you out.